# Random Timeouts when executing DbCommand using Entity Framework and PostgreSQL Database

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, timeoutexception

The exceptions are as follow:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command [Error] Failed
> executing DbCommand ("32,028"ms)...
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query [Error] An exception occurred
> while iterating over the results of a query for context type...
>
> "System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that
> is likely due to a transient failure.  ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException
> (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream  --->
> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during reading attempt...
>
> [Error] An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient
> failure.

I know there is not much to go on. (Almost nothing actually)
Even worse - all I have access to is this log with exceptions.

I have found a solution that work for me (I do not wait all 30 seconds, when I see that I am not getting any response, I simply immediately repeat the request, and it works.)

But this is fighting the symptoms, not the cause.

I would rather know why this is happening.
Thank you in advance.

Edit: After tinkering with the server settings, more specifically - setting Polling=false; in the connection string, the problem is resolved.

I still want to know why.

Edit: The server that connects to the database runs on linux machine, uses ASP NET with MVC architecture.

The database itself is on another linux machine, in the same network.

The error is pretty much this:
https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/3559

And the solution is the same.

Comment: This question lacks details and clarity. We don't know in which environment the database runs, what kind of queries it's about. And what's the meaning of "there is not much to go on"? All we know is: there are random timeout and setting pooling=false helps.

Comment: @GertArnold I am well aware. I was shooting in the dark, when I found this: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/3559. I am not using AWS Lambda, but one of the comments pointed out that they are using "ClearAllPools()". I added this to the connection string, because guess what - I do not have the source of the server. I added some details, but it is still next to nothing.

Comment: WHen do you get this error? Are you executing any query?

Comment: @ShipluMokaddim Yes, the query timeouts. But its not specific query. The same query, repeated when waiting for the other, executes immediately. It seems it is opening new connection for it. A working one. Since I changed Pooling to false, I haven't seen any error.

Comment: If your application is using too many connections simultaneously and the connection pool becomes exhausted, new requests have to wait for an available connection, which may cause timeouts. In this case, consider increasing the MaxPoolSize parameter in the connection string or optimizing the way your application manages database connections. I am assuming that you don't have Long-running queries and latency issues. There's a possibility that the PostgreSQL server might be experiencing high loads or performance issues, causing delays in query execution and timeouts.

Comment: @IndrajeetPatil I was thinking exactly the same, So I created the a demo app, to run some tests. It turns out, I can open like 100 connections, and the exception I get is something like "... remaining connections are reserved for superusers...". The server has no load, and the query is something like "select 1 from mytable" and runs for milliseconds. It is not latency, connection count, or network issue.